# 'TreeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

**I have a Problem in Converting the' TreeQuerySet' object to the QuerySet object**

This is the error I am getting While serializing using DRF

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field name on serializer SubCategoriesSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the TreeQuerySet instance.
Original exception text was:

> 'TreeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'.

Serializer

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'views',
            'title',
            'description',
            'avatar',
            'color'
            )
```

Api Views

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
categories = category.get_children()
categories_serializer = SubCategorySerializer(categories, context={'request': request})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeQuerySet` is in fact a subclass of `QuerySet`

```
categories = category.get_children()
```

returns **multiple** `Category` objects but you are trying to serialize single instance, instead you should serialize a `QuerySet` with additional parameter in serializer `many=true`

```
categories_serializer = SubCategorySerializer(categories, many=true, context={'request': request})
```